# How to access gridview cell value with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a javascript function that I am trying to validate the inputs of a gridview.  My problem is that I cannot get the value of the cell.  Here is what I have:

```
    function fcnCheck() {
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridViewProducts.ClientID %>");
        var cellPivot;

        if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
            for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length-1; i++) {
                cellPivot = grid.rows[i].cells[0];
                cellStatus = grid.rows[i].cells[1];
                if (cellPivot == "Yes" and cellStatus == "") {
                    alert("You must select an answer for all columns if Pivot is yes")
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This line does not work: cellPivot = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

Comment: Why not using a CustomValidator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want (edit)

```
var theDropdown = grid.rows[i].cells[0].elements[0];    
var selIndex = theDropdown.selectedIndex;
cellPivot = theDropdown.options[selIndex].value;
```

Another possibly easier or more reliable way to do this would be to tag the <s>cells</s> controls you want in some way and select them directly?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that it is a dropdown list.

Comment: Edited, try that. I would still suggest you tag the controls you want with an id, name, class or something and then select them using some easy way like jquery, this kind of construct is likely to break and depends on the specific position of the control in the cell. You could also iterate through everything in the cell and look for a dropdown, it just would be easier to tag it.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that.  I am  doing an bulk update so there are 3 dropdowns and 1 textbox for each row.  The updating works fine, I just cannot get the validation to work.

Answer (score 1):

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-get-cell-value-of-gridview-using.html#comment-form

**Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var list = "";
            $("#btnGet").click(function() {
                $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").each(function() {
                    //Skip first(header) row
                    if (!this.rowIndex) return;
                    var age = $(this).find("td:last").html();
                    list += age + "</br>";

                });
                $("#listAge").html(list)
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Cell Value" />
    <div id="listAge">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Create Object of person class
        Person personObject = new Person();
        //Assign Person list to GridView
        GridView1.DataSource = personObject.GetPersonList();
        //Call Bindmethod of GridView
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Person> GetPersonList()
    {
        //Retrun List of Person
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person{ID=1,Name="Person1",Age=32},
            new Person{ID=2,Name="Person2",Age=45},
            new Person{ID=3,Name="Person3",Age=43},
            new Person{ID=4,Name="Person4",Age=21},
            new Person{ID=5,Name="Person5",Age=76},
            new Person{ID=6,Name="Person6",Age=54},

        };

        return list;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function Calculate() 
<br/>
{ 
<br/>
var grid = document.getElementById("<%=GridID.ClientID%>");
<br/> 
var sum = 0; <br/>
for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++)<br/>
 { <br/>
var Cell = grid.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input"); 
<br/>if (!Cell[4].value) {sum  += 0; } else { sum += parseFloat(Cell[4].value);} } 
<br/>
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = sum; 
 }
<br/>
 </script>
------------------------------------------------------------------------



<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current payment" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="cridnvalue" runat="server" Width="70px" BorderStyle="None" onkeyup="CalculateTax();" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="120px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//your gridview id  in my case my gridview is named dgd  and the id comes from
// ClientID
        var myGrid = document.getElementById("<%= dgd.ClientID  %>");
        var oRows = myGrid.rows;
            var k;
            for (k = 1; k < oRows.length; k++)
            {
                var currentRow = myGrid.rows[k];
                //now you can see the 1st,2nd and 3trd column value
                alert(currentRow.cells[1].innerHTML);   
                alert(currentRow.cells[2].innerHTML); 
                alert(currentRow.cells[3].innerHTML);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function rowWisegetcellvalueingridview() {
    ///concat string
    var str1 = "";

    var n = document.getElementById('hdnColumn').value;
    ///concat string 
    var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
    var Inputs = grid.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var Inputsa = grid.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var Inputsspan = grid.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var Input = Inputs.length;
    var j = 0;
    var p = 0;
    var r = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < grid.rows.length - 1; t++) {
        var HdnID1 = Inputs[j].value;
        var HdnID2 = Inputs[j + 1].value;
        var HdnID3 = Inputs[j + 2].value;
        var HdnID4 = Inputs[j + 3].value;
        var HdnID5 = Inputsa[p].innerHTML;
        var HdnID6 = Inputsa[p + 1].innerHTML;
        var HdnID7 = Inputsspan[r].innerHTML;
        var varConcat = "(" + HdnID1 + "," + HdnID2 + "," + HdnID3 + "," + HdnID4 + "," + HdnID5 + "," + HdnID6 + "," + HdnID7 + "),\n";
        n = n.concat(varConcat);
        j = j + 4;
        p = p + 2;
        r = r + 1;
    }
   return false;
}
```