# Access Gridview cell from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've looked at the other post regarding the [Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097736/how-to-access-gridview-cell-value-with-javascript)

But this is insufficient for what I have to ask about.

It's very simple actually, I want to access the cell value from Javascript.

I have tried this:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvUdgivelser.ClientID%>');
var cell = grid.rows[0].cells[5].innerText;
```

But I get a `undefined` in return. If I use the `innerHTML` I get a result with the full HTML, which I am not interested in.

However, how do I pass a `rowIndex` to a function from the gridview button, in order for the code to find out which row was clicked?

Comment: Is the button inside of every GridView row? Then you could pass a reference to the js-function from the button's client click handler.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvUdgivelser.ClientID%>');
var cell = grid.rows[0].cells[5].textcontent;
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JQuery, you can retrieve the cells value like so:

```
var rowIndex = 1;
var cellIndex = 5;
var cellValue = $('#<%= gvUdgivelser.ClientID %> tbody tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') td:eq(' + cellIndex + ')').html();
```

As for determining the row index, you can do this by creating a button within the grid view:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" onclick="getRowIndex(this);" value="Get Row Index" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then make use of JQuery again to determine the row index:

```
function getRowIndex(button) {
    var closestRow = $(button).closest('tr');
    var rowIndex = $('tr').index(closestRow);
}
```

Hope this helps.